# SQL decode or max with multiple rows and blank/null rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to return 1 row, when the table holds both blank/null rows and multiple rows.

Table1.cust (unique)
Table2.prop (3 field create a unique id with one to many cust)
Table3.start (unique [cust, prop and start] some blank/null records exist for cust)

The issue is with the decode and table1, table2 and table 3 join. If I just do a join with table1 and no decode, I get extra records and don't get the null record, but when I combine the three tables, I still do not get the blank/null record.

Example Code

```
select table1.cust,
   table2.prop.(3 fields),
   decode(table3.startdate,' ','1901/01/01',
                            null,'1901/01/01',
                            table3.start)
from table1, table2(subquery), table3(subquery)
where table1 = table2(+)
and (table1.cust = table2.cust(+)
and table2.(3 fields) = table3.(3 fields))
```

Return
Cust1, prop3, date3
Cust2 - Missing
Cust3, prop2, date2
Cust4, prop1, date1

Example Code

```
select table1.cust,
   table2.prop.(3 fields),
   decode(table3.startdate,' ','1901/01/01',
                            null,'1901/01/01',
                            table3.start)
from table1, table2(subquery), table3(subquery)
where table1 = table2(+)
and (table1.cust = table2.cust(+)
and table2.(3 fields) = table3.(3 fields))
```

Return

```
Cust1, prop1, date1 (not the last record)
Cust1, prop2, date2 (not the last record)
Cust1, prop3, date3 - Good
Cust2, prop1, date1 - Good
Cust3, prop1, date1 (not the last record)
Cust3, prop2, date2 - Good
Cust4, prop1, date1 - Good
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure because I don't fully understand your writing, but the issue is most probably with:

```
and table2.(3 fields) = table3.(3 fields))
```

which excludes `null`s on either side (`null = null` is not true in SQL and so in a `where` it causes rows to be excluded).

Try adding `(+)` (or `or xxx is null`) where appropriate to stop excluding the rows you want or, rather, abandon that horrible, obsolete and confusing syntax and go with `from table1 left join table2 on table2.f = table1.f` :)

Also, you may want to read about [ternary logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Application_in_SQL).

Comment: You can only do one left table join and since I am joining 1 to 2 and 2 to 3, it won't allow but one join. Sorry for the horrible, obsolete syntax (plsql), but it is all I know. I have the book for mssql, but I haven't started yet.